# How do I Resolve an application URL from a background thread in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety, httpcontext

The app splits off into two threads; the main web app and a secondary thread used for asynchronous event handling.  The secondary thread receives an event where it needs to send an email with a fully qualified URL of the main app (plus additional route arguments) inside it.

Eg. http://Server.com/App/RouteData?AdditionalArguments

Of course the background thread does not have the luxury of using HttpContext.Current to resolve a Url, because there's no request. No HttpRequest, no HttpContext...

I discovered that most of the methods ASP.NET (even with MVC) uses to build URLs rely on HttpContext.  Does there exist a way to build a fully qualified application URL in ASP.NET without using HttpContext or any of it's derivatives?

I'm looking for a thread-safe method like:

```
UrlHelper.GetApplicationtUrl()
```

Any Ideas?  Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact problem. I ended up storing the url in the web.config file. I did mine like so:

```
<appSettings>
  <!-- Urls -->
  <add key="AppDomain" value="http://localhost:1273/" />
  <add key="ConfirmUrl" value="http://localhost:1273/Auth/Confirm/?code={0}" />
</appSettings>
```

and called it like this in the service layer:

```
string confirmUrl = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfirmUrl"], confirmCode);
```

Comment: After much experimentation, I found this to be the best solution.  Using System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper at Application_Start to find the application url, then assigning it to a static variable in a singleton or passing it as a constructor argument using dependency injection also works.  However, unforeseen failures come into play using this solution, such as receiving a proxy-server base url do to load-balancing.  Configuration seems like the best solution because the target server address (and protocol) cannot always be determined at runtime.  It's best to pre-set it.  Thanks Shawn :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't just use the configuration file, when creating the Thread, use the ThreadStart delegate to provide the base information you need to the new thread.

Comment: I thought about this too, but what if something other than a web request calls the service method? Or something like a worker role for windows azure. (well, for my case anyways).

Comment: Agreed with @Shawn Mclean.  Approaching the situation from this route, the ideal time to invoke HttpContext (to get a base url) would not be ThreadStart because that would again be assuming you have resources that might not be available at that time.  I more favored getting the base url at Application_Start; which happens during a request and is the same time when I subscribe the event to the event handler.